# system of implicit nonlinear differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Here I have a system of nonlinear differential equations:

$
(M+2m)\ddot{x} + m(l_1 \ddot{\theta}_1\cos\theta_1 - l_1\dot{\theta}_1^2\sin\theta_1) + m(l_2\ddot{\theta}_2\cos\theta_2-l_2\dot{\theta}_2^2\sin\theta_2) = F
$

$
l_1\ddot{\theta}_1 + \ddot{x}\cos\theta_1 - g\sin\theta_1 = 0
$

$
l_2\ddot{\theta}_2 + \ddot{x}\cos\theta_2 - g\sin\theta_2 = 0
$

States are defined by me like this:

$x_1 = \theta_1 , x_2 = \dot{x_1} = \dot{\theta}_1,x_3 = \theta_2, x_4 = \dot{x_3} = \dot{\theta}_2,x_5 = x, x_6 = \dot{x_5} = \dot{x}$

I mean actually what I need to do is to linearize this system about all the states are equal to $0$. But I cannot find the $\cdots$ places below

$
\dot{x_1} = x_2 \\
\dot{x_2} = \cdots \\
\dot{x_3} = x_4 \\
\dot{x_4} = \cdots \\
\dot{x_5} = x_6 \\
\dot{x_6} = \cdots \\
$

How can I find $\dot{x_2},\dot{x_4},\dot{x_6}$?

Thanks

Comment: First you need to solve your system for $\ddot x,\,\ddot \theta_1$ and $\ddot \theta_2$. After that you can find what you are looking for.

Comment: I will use Cramer's rule, is this ok for the system of nonlinear differential equations? I mean for $\ddot{x}$... I have done this... I will post it again, will you look at? Thanks by the way.

Comment: $
\ddot{x} = (F*l_1*l_2 + l_1^2*l_2*m*x_2^2*sin(x_1) + l_1*l_2^2*m*x_4^2*sin(x_3) - g*l_1*l_2*m*cos(x_1)*sin(x_1) - g*l_1*l_2*m*cos(x_3)*sin(x_3))/(M*l_1*l_2 + 2*l_1*l_2*m - l_1*l_2*m*cos(x_1)^2 - l_1*l_2*m*cos(x_3)^2)
$

Comment: Your system is linear with respect to the second order derivatives. And I do not think the Cramer's rule is the best option in this situation.

Comment: ok, what else I can do? I found $\ddot{x}$ by using Cramer's rule as above.

Comment: Artem, I couldn't understand what exactly I should do? I'm a math lover, I want to answer this question, or I cannot sleep tonight!!!

Comment: say, you have found $\ddot x=f(x,\dot x,\ldots)$. You now use new variables $u$ such that $\dot x=u$, then your equation turns into $\dot u=f(x,u,\ldots)$, how you require. The same for the other variables.

Comment: Your system is linear with respect to the second order derivatives. And I do not think the Cramer's rule is the best option in this situation. – Artem 1 hour ago

I wonder, what is the best option for this situation?

Comment: Find $\ddot \theta_1$ and $\ddot \theta_2$ from the second and third equations and plug them into the first one. You will find $\ddot x$.

Comment: thank you very much Artem!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put your system

$$
(M+2m)\ddot{x} + m(l_1 \ddot{\theta}_1\cos\theta_1 - l_1\dot{\theta}_1^2\sin\theta_1) + m(l_2\ddot{\theta}_2\cos\theta_2-l_2\dot{\theta}_2^2\sin\theta_2) = F
$$

$$
l_1\ddot{\theta}_1 + \ddot{x}\cos\theta_1 - g\sin\theta_1 = 0
$$

$$
l_2\ddot{\theta}_2 + \ddot{x}\cos\theta_2 - g\sin\theta_2 = 0
$$

into a matrix formulation

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
M+2m & m l_1\cos\theta_1 & ml_2\cos \theta_2\\ 
\cos \theta_1 & l_1 & 0\\
\cos \theta_2 & 0 & l_2
\end{bmatrix}}_{\boldsymbol{M}(\theta_1,\theta_2)}
\dfrac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{\theta_1}\\
\dot{\theta_2}\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}ml_1\sin \theta_1\dot{\theta}^2_1+ml_2\sin\theta_2\dot{\theta}^2_2\\g\sin\theta_1\\g\sin\theta_2 \end{bmatrix}}_{\boldsymbol{f}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\dot{\theta_1},\dot{\theta_2})}+
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}F.
$$

by inverting the mass matrix $\boldsymbol{M}(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, this can be done with many computer algebra systems (e.g. Maple, Python, Mathematica, MATLAB symbolic toolbox) we obtain:

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}x = \dot{x}$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\theta_1 = \dot{\theta}_1$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\theta_2 = \dot{\theta}_2$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}\\\dot{\theta}_1\\\dot{\theta}_2\end{bmatrix}=\boldsymbol{M}(\theta_1,\theta_2)^{-1}\boldsymbol{f}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\dot{\theta_1},\dot{\theta_2})+\boldsymbol{M}(\theta_1,\theta_2)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}F$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No problem, I know it is a late answer but I couldn't resist to answer it because there were no answer :).